# How to access a property of an object within an object C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to make a code that reads the object property of an object before using said ability. In this case, it reads the cooldown of the the ability, then casts the ability if the cooldown equals zero. However, I can't get the code to run without experiencing an error. It will not let me access the property.

```
public class Pug : Dogs
{
    public Pug()
    {
        ability bark = new Ability();
        bark.cooldown = 2;
    }

    public void PugBark()
    {
        if (bark.cooldown == 0)//error occurs on this line
        {
            //He Barks
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is bark? you need to give the code, what is the error, you need to give the error

Comment: Error- 'DogsCode.Pug' does not contain a definition for 'bark' and no accessible extension method 'bark' accepting a first argument of type 'DogsCode.Pug' could be found.

Comment: I shouldn't have included it, that just muddled the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because of your `bark` object the only available in the construct function scope.

I think you can try to let `bark` be a field or property in the `Pug` class

```
public class Pug : Dogs , ThingsDogsDo
{
    private Ability bark;

    public Pug()
    {
        bark = new Ability();
        bark.cooldown = 2;
    }

    public void PugBark()
    {
        if (bark.cooldown == 0)//error occurs on this line
        {
            //He Barks
        }
    }
}
```